# Mean curvature of a surface same as inverse diameter of equivalent sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let $A$ denote, in the plane, the area enclosed by the perimeter $P=\partial A$, and $K=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\kappa(\theta)d\theta$ the mean curvature of $P$ (i.e. the average of the local curvature $\kappa$ all along $P$). We adopt the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. We know that when $A$ reduces to a disk (or $P$ reduces to a circle) of radius $R$, then $K=1/R$.

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following result:

$K=1/\bar{R}$,

where $\bar{R}$ is the radius of the equivalent disk $\bar{A}$, that is, the disk with same area as $A$.

My starting point was to compute $\kappa(\theta) = \frac{r^2+2r'^2-r r''}{(r^2+r'^2)^{3/2}}$, where the prime denotes the derivative of $r(\theta)$. We know that $A=\bar A$, i.e., $\int\int_A rdrd\theta=\pi \bar R^2$, by definition of the equivalent disk (I abusively note $A$ the area of $A$).

Then, upon applying Green's theorem (if not mistaken), $K=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \int_A \frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial r} dr d\theta$. From there, I would combine the two previous equations, but calculations become rather tedious, and I'm not sure if it leads anywhere. If this result is true, there exists maybe a more straightforward way of proving/disproving it?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your claim exactly? Do we assume that $K$ is constant on $S$? What about taking only some part $S'$ of $S$? Now $S$ has the same constant curvature, but smaller area.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MichałMiśkiewicz, I have tried and clarified my statement; I think I was using a confusing wording between surface and area. My problem is 2D.